# Handling Date as Request Params in Spring Boot getting error

Tags: java, sql-server, spring-boot

I'm working on a requirement where i'm passing `key` and `date` as `@RequestParam`, to fetch the list of records between `created_date` and `modified_date` from MSSQL Server db.

> here `key` is mandatory and `date` is optional.

I've got a **GET** request that sends `key` and `date` as `@RequestParam` to Spring Controller.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/getValueFromGC", produces = { MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON_VALUE })
public List<GcAppConfig> getValueFromGC(@RequestParam String key, @RequestParam(required = false)@DateTimeFormat(pattern = "dd-MM-yyyy") Date date) {
   //if date param is not null
    if(date != null) {
        return gcAppConfig.getValueFromGC(key,date);
    }
   //if date param is null fetching the list of all available records
    else {
        return gcAppConfig.getValueFromGC(key);
    }

}
```

Controller fetches the records if `date` param is null. i.e

> URL: localhost:8082/getValueFromGC?key=TOLERANCE&date=

while passing the `date` param in below format

> Url:getValueFromGC?key=TOLERANCE&date=21-01-2019

Here is my service **gcAppConfig** which fetches the record between `created_date` and `modified_date` bypassing `date`

> Note:`created_date` and `modified_date` are in datetime2 format

```
@Query(" Select g from GcAppConfig g where g.isActive=1 and g.keys= :keys" + 
        "  and  :date >=" + 
        "  CAST(g.createdDate AS DATE) and " + 
        " :date <= " + 
        "  CAST(g.modifiedDate AS DATE) ")
public List<GcAppConfig> getValueFromGC(@Param("keys")String keys, @Param("date")Date date);
```

> Could not resolve requested type fo CAST: DATE

Please correct me in Query also if it is wrong. Any suggestion welcomed.
thanks in advance.

Comment: You are not allowed to pass the requestparameter in dd-mm-yyyy format...You can send your date as a string pattern ddMMyyyy and cast it after receiving from the request in java...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has nothing to do with your `Repository`. Error is at the `Controller` level. Do you really have to use `java.sql.Date`? If you used `java.util.Date` it should work fine, especially with `@DateTimeFormat("yyyy-MM-dd")` annotation for the parameter.

Comment: thanks, @Pijotrek, now I'm getting an error in comparison of date between `created_date` and `modified_date`.